# parsing css selector with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am using the CSS selector to scrape data from the web with the beautifulsoup 4 module.

see sample code:

```
# pull website
res = requests.get('https://dailystoic.com/epictetus/')

#parse file
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

# CSS selector
elems = soup.select('body > div.wrap.container > div > main > article > div.entry-content > p:nth-child(1) > em > a:nth-child(3)')

# take content and store in variable
content = elems[0].text.strip()

# print content
print(content)
```

I want the html text from the hyperlink. I don't want the URL, but what the hyperlink says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`:nth-of-type()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) instead of `nth-child()`.

```
import bs4, requests
res = requests.get('https://dailystoic.com/epictetus/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('body > div.wrap.container > div > main > article > div.entry-content > p:nth-of-type(1) > em > a:nth-of-type(3)')
print(elems[0].text)
```

`.text` get what the hyperlink says - the [link text](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp). If you wanted the URL, you'd do:  `elems[0].attrs['href']`

Output:

`Epictetus`