# Why does python parsing table BeatifulSoup do not work on this website as intended?

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am stuck on this website. I've done some small codes to learn about `BeatifulSoup` for the past week, I did some research on how to use it and the respective official documentation. Not only that, but review some tutorials and videos on how to parse a table from websites. I've parsed data from tables using the methods `soup.find()` and `soup.select()` from several websites such as:

1. [Games engine website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines)
2. [MLB stats website](https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/team/147)
3. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-streamed_songs_on_Spotify)

for example, for the [MLB stats website](https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/team/147) I used the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
def connection(url):
    uclient = ureq(url)
    page_html = uclient.read()
    uclient.close()
    soup = bs(page_html, "html.parser")
    return(soup)


soup = connection('https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/team/146')
   
table = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "table-savant"})  #<--using method soup.find()
#table = soup.select("div.table-savant") #<-----------------using method soup.select()   

for n in range(len(table)):
    if (n==9): break 
    content = table[n]
    columns = content.find("thead").find_all("th")    
    column_names = [str(c.string).strip() for c in columns] 
    table_rows = soup.findAll("tbody")[n].find_all("tr")
    l = [] 
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all("td")
        row = [str(tr.text).strip() for tr in td]
        l.append(row)
    print(l)
```

Then convert them into a data frame. But there is one particular **[website](https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/preview?game_pk=634607&game_date=2021-4-4) that I can not retrieve the data** of the tables. I've tried just printing the content with `find()`:

```
def connection(url):
    uclient = ureq(url)
    page_html = uclient.read()
    uclient.close()
    soup = bs(page_html, "html.parser")
    return(soup) 

soup = connection('https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/preview?game_pk=634607&game_date=2021-4-4')
   
table = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "table-savant"})  #<--using method soup.find()
print(table)

result: []
```

With `select()`:

```
table = soup.select("div.table-savant") 
print(table)

result: []
```

With `select()` using CSS path from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215787/parsing-css-selector-with-beautifulsoup):

```
table = soup.select('#preview > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(3) > table:nth-of-type(1) > tbody:nth-of-type(2) > tr:nth-of-type(2) > td:nth-of-type(3)')
print(table)
    
result: []
```

I want to retrieve the stats from the players, but I'm lost. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The tables on that website are loaded using javascript. You'll need to either find the AJAX request(s) made then try to access those URLs directly or you could use something like Selenium that executes javascript.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel I already got it to work with zenos' answer

Comment: While selnium will work, access those apis there will be much more efficient and robust. Also, the data is embeded in the html script tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: The page uses javascript to fetch and display the content, so you cannot just use requests or other similars because javascript code would not be executed.
**Solution**: use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) in order to load the page then parse the content with BeautifulSoup.
Sample code here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(d.page_source)
```

To use `webdriver.Chrome` you will also have to download chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and put the executable in the same folder of your project or in PATH.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, this worked as expected. For curiosity, how can I know if a website uses javascript to fetch and display the content? I'm naive in terms of web development...

Comment: I guessed. In order to confirm that you can disable javascript in your browser (I tried with Chrome) and try to load the page, you'll se that the table is not loaded. Glad I helped.